# How did medieval fishermen work a long line?

Tags: middle-ages

How did medieval fishermen use a long line? What did they use as bait? How many hooks were there? When was it put out? When was it pulled in? I want as many details as possible.

Comment: You might want to narrow down the time range (the medieval period is about a thousand years) and where in the world (fishing techniques could be different in Europe compared to Asia and/or the Americas) you are interested in. Also show any research you've already done.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, although there have been some suggestions of long-line fishing based on Viking-age finds from Orkney and York, no conclusive evidence has yet been found for long-line fishing in Medieval Europe.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might be interested in the paper "[Medieval Fishing](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289503426_Medieval_Fishing)" by Richard Hoffmann, published in 2000, which gives an overview of what we know about Medieval fishing.